# Consider a matrix $A$ with $n=2m$ and $a_{ii}=a_{n+1-i,n+1-i} = a_{i,n+1-i}=a_{n+1-i,i} = i$ for $i=1,\dots, m$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Consider a matrix $A$ with $n=2m$ and $a_{ii}=a_{n+1-i,n+1-i} =
> a_{i,n+1-i}=a_{n+1-i,i} = i$ for $i=1,\dots, m$. Find $||A||_2$.

**My attempt:**

An example of such a matrix would be $(n=4, m=2)$, $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&1\\0&2&2&0\\0&2&2&0\\1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ The matrix is symmetric, therefore $||A||_2=\rho(A)$, where $\rho(A)=\max_i |\lambda_i|$ (where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of  $A$). The rank of this matrix is $m$, meaning that that the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is at least $m$. Now, $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i = 2\sum_i^m i = m(m+1)$.

The eigenvalues of the example that I gave are $0$ (algebraic multiplicity 2), $2$ (AM 1) and $4$ (AM 1). So, I would expect that in the general case $0, m$ and $m^2$ are eigenvalues, which $\rho(A)=m^2$ and therefore $||A||_2$. How can I show this rigorously?

Thanks!

Comment: My expectation was incorrect, f.ex. $n=6$ gives $0$ (AM 3), $2,4,6$ (each AM 1). So, I would now expect $0,2,4,6,\dots,2m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reorder the basis by reversing the order of the last $m$ basis elements then the matrix is the tensor product of $\text{Diag}(1,2,\dots,m)$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1\\1 &1\end{bmatrix}$. The latter matrix diagonalises to $\text{Diag}(2,0)$. The upshot is that your original  matrix is similar to $\text{Diag}(2,4,6,\dots, 2m,0,0,\dots, 0)$ and all is clear.

Comment: Very elegant solution, but I don't understand your first sentence: 'reversing the order of the last $m$ basis elements', could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Instead of basis eg $u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4$ use $u_1, u_2, u_4, u_3$.